# Problema al cerrar modal Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy realizando un CRUD con JQuery y PHP, utilizo Bootstrap para los modales de nuevo usuario y editar usuario. El problema es que cuando edito un registro cierro el modal automáticamente con JQuery pero se queda la pantalla un obscura, como si el modal no se hubiese cerrado por completo. No siempre pasa, regularmente es cuando edito 2 veces seguidas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MODAL:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUpdateUser" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form id="formUpdateUser" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><b>Update user</b></h6>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group my-0">
                                <input type="number" id="idUserU" name="idUserU" class="form-control form-control-sm d-none">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nameU">Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="nameU" name="nameU" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastnameU">Lastname:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="lastnameU" name="lastnameU" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="emailU">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" id="emailU" name="emailU" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phoneU">Phone:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="phoneU" name="phoneU" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-4 mx-1" id="btnUpdateUser" name="btnUpdateUser"> <i class="fas fa-save mr-2"></i> Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-4 mx-1" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fas fa-times mr-2"></i> Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
function updateUser() {
    var data = $('#formUpdateUser').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'php/users-backend.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(e) {
            if (validateEmptyForm('formUpdateUser') > 0) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'warning',
                    title: '¡Debes llenar todos los campos!',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 2000
                });
            } else {    
                if (e == 1) {
                    $('#modalUpdateUser').modal('hide');
                    $('#formUpdateUser')[0].reset();
                    $('#users').load('index.php');
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: '¡Guardado exitosamente!',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: '¡Error al guardar!',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar amigos, gracias de antemano.

Comment: eso sucede por que el backdrop se queda bloqueado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976560/4717133

Comment: aun asi no logro reproducir el error con el código que muestras. puedes indicar la version de Bootstrap y jquery que usas???

Comment: Sí @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, la versión de JQuery es 3.3.1 y la de Bootstrap es 4.6

Comment: pues no logro reproducir el error, se que existe pero no logro reproducirlo

Comment: pasate por el chat en español: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol